# Переполнение/утечка памяти программы - C#

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, память, парсер

Пишу программу для парсинга одного сайта. Сам сайт парсится с помощью CsQuery. Нужно за раз обработать нужный диапазон страниц сайта. Задаётся начальная и конечная ссылки для парсинга и программа в несколько потоков перебирает все страницы в диапазоне и извлекает нужную информацию в List, что бы после окончания сохранить всё в файл. Нужное количество потоков запускается, и они по очереди берут из счётчика текущей страницы свой номер и работают с ним. В потоках написан цикл While, что бы они не закрывались, пока не спарсили последнюю страницу. После окончания парсинга отдельно сохраняется вся информация в List. Но проблема в том, что парсится будут большие диапазоны страниц больше миллиона, а при тестовом запуске на диапазоне в 10 000 страниц программа начинает занимать в памяти больше 1,5 гигабайт. В отдельной программе пробовал заполнять List случайными данными, по типу тех, что должны были быть извлечены. Добавил 100 000 строк, и размер оперативной памяти, используемой программы не превышал 100 мегабайт. Парсинг так же работает правильно, никаких избыточных данных он не добавляет. Я грешу на мою неправильную работу с потоками, и то, что сборщик мусора не уничтожает данные с прошлых проходов парсинга. Пробовал разные способы так и не решил проблему с утечкой памяти. Помогите найти ошибку, или подсказать более правильный метод работы с потоками. Код прикладываю.

```
class Program
{
    static int begin_of_post = 2950774;      //начальный индекс постов
    static int end_of_post = 2951774;        //конечный индекс
    static int current_post;                 //текущий пост для потоков

    static List<string> list_posts = new List<string>();   //список хранения данных о постах

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000000000;   // количество одновременных соединений

        current_post = begin_of_post;

        Thread my_tr;                               
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)            //запуск потоков
        {
            my_tr = new Thread(parse_site);
            my_tr.Start();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
        save_to_file();
    }

    static void parse_site()
    {
        while (current_post <= end_of_post)
        {
            int link_to_post =current_post;                 //ссылка на пост
            Interlocked.Increment(ref current_post);        //инкремент счётчика

            CQ cq;
            try
            {
                cq = CQ.CreateFromUrl("http://site.ru/" + link_to_post);        // загрузка кода страницы
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error " + link_to_post);
                continue;
            }

            string post_info;
            ...
            //сам парсинг сайта
            ...

            int current = int.Parse(link_to_post) - begin_of_post;          
            int end = end_of_post - begin_of_post;
            Console.WriteLine("Обработана ссылка " + current.ToString() + " ИЗ " + end.ToString());

            Thread my_tr_save=new Thread(save_post);
            my_tr_save.Start(post_info);
        }
    }

    static void save_post(object post_info)
    {
        ...
        // Парсинг информации о странице
        ...

        lock (list_posts)
        {
            list_posts.Add(post_info.ToString());
        }
    }      

    static void save_to_file()
    {
                    ...
        //сохранение строк list_posts в файл
                    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Возьмите любой профайлер памяти (хотя бы студийный) и сравните два снимка - в начале запуска, и когда программа отъест память.

Comment: и что именно попадает в list_posts? все содержимое постов?

Comment: Нет, в list_posts попадает строка, длинной не более 100 символов.

Comment: Больше всего ссылко создаётся на ConcurrentStack+Node<Object> . за 1000 выполнений около 500 ссылок. И он каждый объект занимает по 2 мегабайта. Но что это? И где можно посмотреть?

Comment: _"В потоках написан цикл While, что бы они не закрывались"_ -- лучше освобождайте поток сразу как он вам не нужен. И лучше берите потоки из ThreadPool или используйте Task.

Comment: вы ConcurrentStack где-то в коде используете? если нет - смотрите в профайлере корень для любой такой ноды - поймете где неявная ссылка

Comment: _"парсится будут большие диапазоны страниц больше миллиона"_ -- и в list_posts вы храните адреса миллионов страниц? лучше адреса сразу записывать в файл log.txt

Comment: _"так и не решил проблему с утечкой памяти."_ -- проблема скорее всего в методе CQ.CreateFromUrl.

Answer (score 3):

Вообще для того чтобы судить об утечке, нужно использовать профайлер, сделать два внэпшота (до и после) и посмотреть, что отнимает память.

---

Какие навскидку есть проблемы в этом коде:

1. Внутри каждого из потоков, читающих страницы, вы в цикле непрерывно создаете новые потоки:

   ```
   Thread my_tr_save=new Thread(save_post);
   my_tr_save.Start(post_info);
   ```

   Во-первых, вы плодите множество потоков, а они занимают память. Во-вторых, это избыточно, потому что вы и так уже внутри отдельного потока. И разносить в разные потоки парсинг и сохранение для начала нет смысла.
2. К переменной `current_post` обращаются разные потоки, причем небезопасным способом. Теоретически может случиться так, что каждый пост обрабатывается несколько раз и вы получаете дубликаты страниц в вашем конечном списке, а значит, лишнюю память. Вам нужно атомарно выполнять условие `current_post <= end_of_post` с последующим инкрементом и возвращать актуальное значение, а в теле цикла пользоваться эти значением.

   ```
   static bool HasPostsToParse(out current)
   {
       lock (lockObject)
       {
           // к переменной current_post обращаетесь только в этом методе
           if (current_post <= end_of_post)
           {
               current = ++current_post;
               return true;
           }
           else
           {
               current = current_post;
               return false;
           }
       }
   }

   static void parse_site()
   {
       int current;
       while (HasPostsToParse(out current))
       {
           // используете локальную переменную current
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Не надо Volatile.Read - оно не снимет гонку! Надо просто использовать возвращаемое значение у Interlocked.Increment.

Comment: @PavelMayorov а в `while (current_post <= end_of_post)` что прикажете делать? Хотя насчет гонки вы правы, по-хорошему нужно синхронизировать блок кода с этим условием и последующий инкремент.

Comment: да, ваш новый вариант выглядит куда лучше. Я бы, правда, вместо lock обошелся бы простым Interlocked.Increment. Увеличил бы, потом запомнил - и в конце уже проверял.

Comment: Новые потоки для сохраниения создаются, потому что в самом методе сохранения выполняется множество операций, и оставлять его выполнение в том же потоке будет сильно тормозить его, и уменьшать производительность парсинга. Поэтому я и вынес его в отдельный поток.

Comment: @PavelMayorov проверка же должна идти до инкремента.

Comment: У меня current_post инкрементируется атомарным способом. И следовательно один пост не может обработаться 2 раза. Из за сравнения, он может немного выйти за границы диапозона, но на тестах такого не происходило, и это не критично

Comment: @Kipik тогда лучше воспользоваться шаблоном producer/consumer: есть `x` потоков, которые парсят сайт и складывают промежуточный результат в коллекцию (`BlockingCollection`), и `y` потоков, которые берут из этой коллекции промежуточные результаты и сохраняют их. Это будет гораздо эффективнее, чем на каждой итерации в 10-ти потоках создавать новый поток.

Comment: @Kipik да, инкремент безопасный. А вот чтение -- нет. Чтение общих данных не является потокобезопасным и его тоже нужно синхронизировать! Т.е. поток1 может обработать пост с id = 1, увеличить счетчик до 2, а потом поток2 считает устаревшее значение id = 1 и снова обработает этот пост.

Comment: не может он потом считать id=1, потому что атомарный инкремент ставит все необходимые барьеры. Вот считать id=1, а потом отдать управление 1му потоку - запросто.

Comment: Да, `producer/consumer` - неплохой вариант. Но и выход счетчика за границы - совершенно не страшно, особенно если поставить проверку после инкремента.

Answer (score 3):

в вашем случае у вас рождаются новые потоки, каждому из которых выделяется стек по 4 мегабайта и ни один из потоков не может закончить работу и освободить память, потому что каждый из потоков закручивается while (current_post <= end_of_post) аж до конца выполнения всей работы вообще. Поэтому у вас будет постоянный прирост памяти за счет стеков аж до конца работы

более правильный метод с потоками это TPL + правильное понимание IO-bound потоков и перелопатить весь этот миллион страниц можно одними потоками из пула.

автор просил примеров как лучше делать в таких случаях (конечно парсер автора может не позволять этого)

```
 class SomeNetParser
{
    private const int ThreadCount=20;
    private CountdownEvent _countdownEvent;
    private SemaphoreSlim _throttler;

    public void Check(IList<string> urls)
    {
        _countdownEvent = new CountdownEvent(urls.Count);
        _throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(ThreadCount); 

        foreach (var url in urls)
        {
            await _throttler.WaitAsync(ct);
            ProccessUrl(url);
        }
     _countdownEvent.Wait();
    }

    private async void ProccessUrl(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            var page = await new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(url)); 
            ProccessResult(page);
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphoreSlim.Release();
            _countdownEvent.Signal();
        }
    }

    private void ProccessResult(string page){/*....*/}
}
```

нужно не забыть метод Check вызвать не UI потоке. CountdownEvent нужен, чтобы после выхода из цикла дождался последней задачи.
минусом данного решения является то, что он удерживает 1 поток.

CountdownEvent можно выбросить и содержимое Check заменить на

```
var allTasks = new List<Task>();

foreach (var url in urls)
{
    await _throttler.WaitAsync(ct);
    allTasks.Add(ProccessUrl(url));
}

await Task.WhenAll(allTasks);
```

и ProccessUrl должен возвращать Task
В этом случае allTasks  будет накапливаться миллионом экземпляров Task и я даже не знаю, как быстро Task.WhenAll будет их проверять

Есть еще вариант с LINQ, но он сложно понимаемый для новичков.

зы: WebClient плохо подходит для этого. Он написан неправильно и выполняет часть своей работы с потоке который его вызвал и это так и не починили. HttpClient лучше подходит.

Comment: _"allTasks = new List<Task>();"_ -- так делать необязательно, т.к. есть TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent. посмотрите [UPDATE в моем ответе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/476958/revisions)

Comment: @Stack Не для моего пример. действительно внешняя задача будет дожидаться окончания вложенных. Но в моем примере эта внешняя задача не определена. Цепляться же к неявной задаче (если Task.Run находится выше вызываемого метода) нельзя по причине того, что после выполнения цикла может быть еще код и Task.WhenAll(allTasks) как раз и гарантирует, что к моменту окончания цикла, но **незаконченной** внешней задачи все задачи цикла будут завершены.

Answer (score 0):

Для параллельной обработки данных в заданном диапазоне можно использовать Parallel.For. Если взять части из вашего кода, то будет примерно так:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
// ...

int begin_of_post = 2950774;      //начальный индекс постов
int end_of_post = 2951774;        //конечный индекс

var list_posts = new BlockingCollection<string>();
Parallel.For(begin_of_post, end_of_post, (current_post) => {
    // ...
    var cq = CQ.CreateFromUrl("http://site.ru/" + link_to_post);
    list_posts.Add(link_to_post);
    // ... код для парсинга и т.д.
    save(file_name);
});

save_to_file(list_posts);
```

---

UPDATE:

Если надо скачать много страниц, распарсить их и сохранить в файлы, а также получить лог, то можно сделать примерно так:

```
public class App {
    BlockingCollection<string> log;      // для синхронизации вывода в log
    public Run(int start, int end) {
        log = new BlockingCollection<string>();
        Task.Run(() => {
            foreach(var s in log) {
                // тут пишем в log.txt
            }
        });
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            // для каждого запроса создаем отдельный Task   
            foreach (var page in Enumerable.Range(start, end))
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Download(page), 
                   TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
        }).Wait();   // ждем завершение всех запущенных Task'ов

        log.CompleteAdding();   // завершим Task логирования
    }
    void Download(int page) { // выполняется в отдельном потоке
        var url = "http://...." + page;
        log.Add(url);
        try {
            var html = RequestPage(url);
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Parse(url, html), 
               TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
        } catch(...) {
            log.Add("fail");
        }
    }
    void Parse(string url, string html) { // выполняется в отдельном потоке 
        // тут парсим html и сохраняем его в файл
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33351/discussion-on-answer-by-stack-----c).