# Запуск информации перед нажатием кнопки c#

Tags: c#

Есть программа для вывода информации из интернета. Загрузка информации занимает некоторое время. Как сделать что бы при запуске программы загружалась информация в переменную, а после нажатия определённой кнопки информация выводилась в Textbox или label из переменной?

Используется xNet

Comment: для параллельного скачивания и вывода уведомлений -- пример [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476910/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-c/476958#476958) после update.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете в `OnLoad` формы сделать вызов асинхронного метода, который осуществит запрос и запишет результат например в поле формы.

Comment: Располагать такой метод в конструкторе -- не лучшая идея. Я бы воспользовался событием, например, `OnLoad`.

Comment: Согласен. Года 3 не пользовался этой технологией, подзабылось :) Поправил ответ.

Comment: Покаите, пожалуйста как сделать асинхронный метод

Answer (score 0):

асинхронные методы пишутся примерно так:

```
public async void OnLoad()
{
    // some actions
    await LoadInfo() // метод, который занимает время, await его запускает в отдельном
                     // потоке, а выполнение кода идет дальше. Когда он выполнится -
                     // сработает тригер и информация обновится в представлении
    // MyInfo = await LoadInfo() // или же так
    // other actions
}
```

LoadInfo в данном случае должен возвращать Task или может возвращать Task в общем случае. Таким способом обычно делаются все асинхронные действия в UI

Comment: Не вполне верно, `await` не запускает метод в отдельном потоке.